# The function e - where increasing and decreasing

Tags: derivatives

I have to find where $(x+\frac{1}{x})^{x}$ is increasing and decreasing.

I tried to derivate it , and I have now -
$f'(x) = (x+\frac{1}{x})^{x} \left (ln(x+\frac{1}{x}) + (\frac{x-1}{x})  \right )$

Im pretty stuck, I dont know how to find where $f'(x) > 0 $ and where $f'(x) <0 $.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

When $x>0$
$$x+\frac{1}{x} >1$$
When $x<0$
$$x+\frac{1}{x} <1$$

Also note that $$\ln(a) >0 \text{ when } a>1$$.

However, keep in mind that a function may increase on an interval without having a derivative defined at all points, for example $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Comment: $ln(x)$ is undefined for $x ≤ 0$,
So $x$ have to be positive ?

Comment: Note that in this case you have $\ln(x+\frac{1}{x})$

Comment: Ok , so $(x+\frac{1}{x})^{x}$ have to be positive , and because of that $x$ must be greater than $1$.
And because of this $f'(x) > 0$ , and $f(x)$ is increasing always ?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you made a mistake in your derivative.  [WolframAlpha gives a different result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%28%28x%2B1%2Fx%29%5Ex%29%2Fdx)

Now using the hint given by [Daniel](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1612577) you should figure it out.

Comment: Ok. $f'(x) = \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\left(-\frac{2}{x^2+1}+\ln \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+1\right)$,
I still dont figure it out.

$\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ have to be positive, now what ?

Comment: $1-\frac{2}{x^2+1} > 0 \rightarrow \frac{x^2+1-2}{x^2+1} > 0 \rightarrow \frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1} > 0
\rightarrow x^2-1 > 0  \rightarrow  $ 
$(x-1)(x+1)>0$

Comment: You are looking at increasing of decreasing values so by definition we are looking for Real solutions. That implies x > 0. Now, if x > 0 then $(x + \frac{1}{x}) > 1$. And thus all you need to figure out is when $ln(x+\frac{1}{x}) + \frac{x^2 -1}{x^2+1} > 0$

Comment: What do you mean "increasing of decreasing" ?
I dont understand why $x>0$ .

Comment: If x < 0 then the derivative (and the function too) becomes imaginary. Imaginary numbers aren't "bigger" or "smaller" than 0. Thus, since you are looking for $f'(x) < 0$ or $f'(x) > 0$ we look only at x > 0.

Comment: Ahh ok.
Now i have to find where $ln(x+\frac{1}{x}) + \frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1} > 0 $.
Can you give me some hint ?

Comment: Write it as $ln(x+\frac{1}{x}) > \frac{1-x^2}{x^2+1}$. Consider two different cases: $0<x<1$ and $x > 1$

Comment: How can i know what is the value of $ln(x+\frac{1}{x})$ ?

Comment: You don't need the actual value. Look at Daniel's hint.

Comment: I know its positive. That's all.